# How to create all possible combinations of a list which has lists inside of it?

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list which looks like this

```
[['Macau', 'United Kingdom', 'India'],
 ['United States', 'China'],
 ['China', 'Australia']]
```

And I want to have all possible combinations of those countries but combinations need to be limited to the small lists, I dont want them to mix.

For example I want to have

```
[('Macau', 'India'), ('United Kingdom', 'India'), ('Macau', 'United Kingdom'), ('United States', 'China')...]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `itertools.combinations` or `itertools.product`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements). Just do this separately for each list in your list-of-lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [['Macau', 'United Kingdom', 'India'], ['United States', 'China'],  ['China', 'Australia']]

print([list(combinations(group, 2)) for group in lst])
```

Returns

```
[[('Macau', 'United Kingdom'),
  ('Macau', 'India'),
  ('United Kingdom', 'India')],
 [('United States', 'China')],
 [('China', 'Australia')]]
```

Comment: The case is that I dont want to have all possible combinations but to have possible combinations within each single list, I dont want to mix them all.

Comment: @Axton, code has been updated

Answer (score 1):

use set and itertools to find all possible combinations by groupings

```
import itertools

data=[['Macau', 'United Kingdom', 'India'],
 ['United States', 'China'],
 ['China', 'Australia']]

lst=[]
for item in data:
    result=list(itertools.combinations(set(item), 2))
    lst.append(result)
    #print(result)
    
print(lst)
```

output:

```
[[('United Kingdom', 'Macau'), ('United Kingdom', 'India'), ('Macau', 'India')], [('United States', 'China')], [('Australia', 'China')]]
```